# How to set up the Wistia ruby gem in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

The wistia-api gem (https://github.com/wistia/wistia-api) says that I have to set the Wistia password like so:

```
Wistia.password = 'your-api-password-here'
```

Where do I add this line of code in my rails project?

I've added it to environment.rb but when I run rails console it gives me an unknown constant error.

Answer (score 2):

you have to make sure you install the right gem first, in gemfile put

`gem wistia-api`
then run `bundle install`
if you are using rails 4, in `/config/initializers` folder create a file called `wistia_api.rb`, write:

```
require 'wistia'

Wistia.use_config!(:wistia => {
  :api => {
    :password => ENV['WISTIA_API_PASSWORD'],
    :format => 'json'
  }
})
```

then you should be good to use it in rails console

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an unknown constant error because the Wistia module isn't loaded yet. You need to `require 'wistia'` before trying to call it.

Generally it's best to do things like this in an initializer, so you could create config/initializers/wistia.rb and put in it:

```
require 'wistia'

Wistia.password = 'your-api-password-here'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the documentation of the wistia gem, there is an option to put these credentials into a yml config file:
https://github.com/wistia/wistia-api#configuration-options